# How to set ImageButton's foreground image to nothing

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some ImageButtons being used as a segmented control each has a background set, and the forground image will be a checkmark showing which one of the 3 is currently selected. The other 2 buttons should have no forground image. The images are defined in XML (see below).

```
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/style_light_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/style_color_segment_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/style_button_segment_height"
                android:background="@drawable/button_segmented_light"
                android:src="@drawable/icons_checkmark_dark" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/style_sepia_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/style_color_segment_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/style_button_segment_height"
                android:background="@drawable/button_segmented_sepia"
                android:src="@drawable/icons_checkmark_dark" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/style_dark_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/style_color_segment_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/style_button_segment_height"
                android:background="@drawable/button_segmented_dark"
                android:src="@drawable/icons_checkmark_light" />
```

In code when one is clicked I will clear the checkmark from the 2 that were not clicked and make sure its added to the one that was clicked.

```
ImageButton lightModeButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style_light_button);
ImageButton sepiaModeButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style_sepia_button);
ImageButton darkModeButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.style_dark_button);
```

I have tried both the `setImageBitmap(null)` and `setImageDrawable(null)` but they both crash.

```
lightModeButton.setImageBitmap(null);
sepiaModeButton.setImageDrawable(null);
darkModeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons_checkmark_light);
```

How can I clear the image, or at just hide the foreground image while leaving the background image showing?

Comment: simply set imgButton.setImageResource(0);

Comment: Ok tried that and still getting null pointer crash so I guess my problem is the button is null for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: @jamone - probably. setImageDrawable(null); should work fine along with setImageResource(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Transclude drawable for example, on you Drawable directory create file 
transclude_drawable.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

After that just set `ImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.transclude_drawable);`
Do not forget to change the `ImageButton` with your references, for example `lightModeButton`.

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful in another part of the app.

Answer (score 2):

from [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) :

```
 public void setBackgroundResource (int resid)
```

*Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object **or 0 to remove the background.***

i don't know if it will work with `setImageResource(int resId)` so give this a try :

```
sepiaModeButton.setImageResource(0);
```

instead of

```
sepiaModeButton.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Comment: while `sepidModeButton.setImageResource(0)` does work it doesn't work predictably. Sometimes after its called the checkmark still shows, and other times it disappears. I ended up creating a transparent drawable.

Comment: i think because you should remove the background as well or not ?